# datebase locked error(sqlite)

Tags: android, sqlite

In this app I want to fetch question from the db that I have made using Firefox sqlite manager.

When I run the code I get a **db locked** in the error log and I'm unable to display the content in the `textview`.

**AptitudeActivity**

```
public class AptitudeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button next;
    private Button previous;
      private TextView qdisply,adisplay;
     int counter=0;
    private String v;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        qdisply = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       adisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        previous.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void onClick(View arg) {

        switch(arg.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            counter++;
            upper up=new upper(this);
            up.open();
            // here i want to display based on the counter value which will be +1 when the button is clicked


            up.close();




        break;
        case  R.id.button2:
        //not defined till now  
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

---

**insertq**

```
public class upper {
    static String path;
    insertq q;
    private String dispa;
    String dispq;

    static SQLiteDatabase db1;
    static Context ourcontext;
    static String mydb = "APTITUDE.sqlite";
    static Boolean dbchk;

    private static class insertq extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private String dbpath;

        public insertq(Context context) {
            super(context, mydb, null, 1);
            path = "/data/data/"
                    + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/";

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            boolean addb = chechkdb();
            if (!addb) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {

            }
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            InputStream myInput = ourcontext.getAssets().open(mydb);

            String outFileName = path + mydb;

            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }

        private Boolean chechkdb() {
            dbpath = path + mydb;

            SQLiteDatabase check = null;
            check = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            if (check != null) {
                dbchk = true;
            } else {
                dbchk = false;
            }
            return dbchk;

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }

    public void fetchqan() {

    String qu="SELECT QUESTION,ANSWER FROM QNA WHERE QID=1 ";
    q.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db1.rawQuery(qu, null);
dispq=c.getString(1);
dispa=c.getString(2);

    }

    public upper(Context c) {
        ourcontext = c;
    }

    public upper open() {

        q = new insertq(ourcontext);
        db1 = q.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void close() {
        q.close();
    }

}
```

**stacktrace**

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception SQLiteException))   
    upper$insertq(SQLiteOpenHelper).getWritableDatabase() line: 96  
    upper.open() line: 112  
    AptitudeActivity.onClick(View) line: 41 
    Button(View).performClick() line: 2485  
    View$PerformClick.run() line: 9080  
    ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: 06-17 09:02:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)

Comment: Add the full StackTrace.

Comment: i don't know how to get stack trace

Comment: any help me with the stacktrace